# Convert a polygone in space, to a plane

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

I have a surface defined by a list of 3D points (X,Y,Z). (so all vectors are coplanars)
I would like to convert that on a plane (X,Y).
I am looking for a formula to convert that polygon using vectors, but until now only found a solution offering this :

- Calculate length of each segment.
- Calculate angles between each of them
- Then I can find the X,Y coordinates with that.

But I think there may exist a vectorial solution for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find two vectors parallel to the plane by taking differences of points in the plane, such as $\vec v_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)-(x_0,y_0,z_0),\;\vec v_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)-(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, then use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) on $\vec v_1,\vec v_2$ to get an orthonormal basis $\hat u_1,\hat u_2$ for the plane, and finally take [dot products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to get points $(x',y')$ in 2D: $x'=(x,y,z)\cdot\hat u_1,\;y'=(x,y,z)\cdot\hat u_2$.

Comment: wow lot of new things for me (well maybe did it 20 years ago...) would you know a good website where I could learn back mathematics, please?